# media query not changing class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap5 and adding a separate stylesheet as the last stylesheet in the list, I am trying to style the margins of the class .content  I have this code at the end of my stylesheet...

```
.content {
        width: 100vw;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: 80vh;
        padding: 0;
    }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
.content {
        width: 70vw;
        margin-left: 15vw;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 15vh;
        margin-bottom: 15vh;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: 80vh;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

The web page uses <main class="content> wrapped around the content of the page.

The result I am wanting is to have the margins at zero on a mobile device, and a width of 100vw, but when I test it the width and margins of the media query are used even on mobile devices.

Can anybody see where I have gone wrong?

**ADDED AS REQUESTED

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NC Commodities Conference of Soybeans, Corn, Small Grains, and Cotton Producers</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: min-width means anything that size or larger.  Max-width is anything smaller to that size. With smartphones and tablets resolution is getting better and better, make sure that you know the size of the phone you are testing on, Chrome has the ability for you to size things to match your phones resolution when you hit f12, test on there before trying it out on your phone.

Comment: @Danimal Thanks for that. I started off with width 100vw as the 'regular' class then made it 70vw if the screen was 768px or more,  is this wrong?  I've tested on my Samsung and it picks up the media query, and tested using the inspect feature of chrome with many various options, all seem to take the media query details whatever their width

Comment: Are you sure something isn't overriding your CSS? Your media queries are correct.

Comment: @BillTeale try increasing your 768px to a higher value (like 1100px just to test) and seeing if your phone does not pick it up it could be that your phone has a higher res.  Does it also stay the same if you are in portrait vs landscape mode on the phone? are you in desktop mode on your phone?

Comment: @disinfor yes that's right, when the page is showing on mobile it is still showing the width of 70vw and the left and right margins

Comment: @BillTeale If none of that works, in chrome developer mode highlight the line where the content class is in the elements window and check the styles  window on the right, verify that your media query is being selected and check to see if it is not being overwritten by other css

Answer (score 1):

You have to change min-width propety to max-width.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
.content {
        width: 70vw;
        margin-left: 15vw;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 15vh;
        margin-bottom: 15vh;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: 80vh;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

This max-width propety means, is “If [device width] is greater than or equal to 768px(accordingy to the example), then do {…}”.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
```

this min-width implies here as,“If [device width] is greater than or equal to 768px, then do {…}”

Comment: No they don't the code outside of the @media is for the mobile. I've tried the code and seems to work ok for me, not sure what else could be the issue. Could you post your <head>...</head>

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question. They want the opposite of what you provided.

Comment: @Martin I added the head tags to the bottom of the original question.

Comment: @Martin the entire code of the page and the css is at https://jsfiddle.net/BillTeale/ruztkdLc/

Comment: @BillTeale, strange I've just copied your code and made sure it's links to BootStrap and added a bit more html and all  is working, you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/trekmp00/emvu76qy/3/

Comment: @Martin yes it is really weird! I just noticed on my page too that the col-md-6 does not change on smaller devices, still keeps the content in two columns. It must be the bootstrap5 link I have, I'll try set that again and hopefully it will fix the matter. Thanks for helping I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Martin I just grapped the Bootstrap5 cdn again from the official site (5.02) and the media query for col-md-6 is controlled by the media (min-width 768px) style in any sized view. Wierd!

Comment: @BillTeale for your columns col-lg-6 have you tried adding col-12 as well so that on smaller screens it will go full width

Comment: @Martin I thought it automatically changed on smaller devices, is that not the case anymore?

Comment: It does, I just like to make sure. BTW, did my code work ok for you?

Comment: Hi @Martin  no matter what I did I could not get it to work. I am going to start from a blank page tomorrow and see if I can't get it working properly. I think a clean page with a fresh mind should solve whatever it is that is blocking it from working properly. I really appreciate yoru assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your link tags at `html` file which you connect `bootstrap.css` and `your.css` to project?. You should link `your.css` at the end comparing the other css files.

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="your.css">
```

Comment: _Using Bootstrap5 and adding a separate stylesheet as the last stylesheet in the list_ OP is already doing this.

Comment: yes they are in the correct position